# How to improve sqlicifer performance?

Tags: sqlcipher

I have a very small encrypted sqlite test database. I run a very simple select: just one record from the table which contains one record. This request takes very significant time: 0.3 sec.

```
lesnik@westfall:~/Projects/ls$ cat sql_enc.sql
PRAGMA KEY = "DUMMYKEYDUMMYKEY";
SELECT * FROM 'version';
lesnik@westfall:~/Projects/ls$
lesnik@westfall:~/Projects/ls$ time sqlcipher rabbits_enc.sqlite3 < sql_enc.sql
key         ver
----------  ----------
1           aaa

real    0m0.299s
user    0m0.297s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Experiments show that the time doesn't depend on number of requests in script and doesn't depend on size of database (this test database is just 5kb, result is the same on 500kb databases)

There is no such problem if database is not encrypted.

Performance is slightly better on another linux installation (in different Virtual Box on the same host). And there is no this problem on yet another linux installation (script execution time is about 0.001s there), so I believe this is some problem with environment. But I have no idea how to investigate this problem further. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We provide general performance guidance for utilizing SQLCipher [here](https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/sqlcipher-performance/14)